# copying the 2nd part of a command and putting it on the end of the response

Tags: javascript, discord.js

how would I put the 2nd part of a command at the end of the bot's response.

example:

me: !example example.html

bot: example.com/example.html

another example:

me: !example example2.html

bot: example.com/example2.html

Comment: do you need replace ! for .com ?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere no

Comment: tell me if my answer helps, ill modify if its necesary

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```js
function convert(me){
  var transform = me.replace('!', '').split(' ');
  transform[0] += '.com/';
  var bot = transform.join('');
  return bot
}

console.log(convert('!example example2.html'));
```

Comment: sorry uhh im a big boi beginner can i send u the code and then u insert the code in?

Comment: sure, what do you need exactly?